# Snap Store require authentication to install application

Tags: snap, snap-store, 23.04

Back to Ubuntu after long time away from it, installed latest version 23.04. When I opened snap store gui to install application, snap store showing error message:

> Unable to install app: authentication was required

[image]

This error also happened with flatpak store
Never facing this problem before

How do I automatically authenticate using snap store?

Answer (score 0):

It's asking for your superuser password, same as if you were using sudo for a command line install. Most software installs require you to authenticate for temporary root access, whether you're using a GUI-enabled package distribution interface or a CLI in a terminal window.

Comment: wew I am certainly it did not happen before. Did this change happen recently ?

Answer (score 0):

It isn't a "change." Access to the root file system in Linux always requires authentication unless you're already logged in as root (which is a really bad thing to do). Thus, when you install an app from the snap store and that installation requires temporary root access, you're prompted for your password (and that password, ideally, is non-trivial and complex).